how to prevent swipe event from passing through the top div to the layer below
I have a leaflet map on which I show a sliding info panel when the user clicks on a marker. It looks like so
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│           map           │
│                         │
│┌───────────────────────┐│
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││                       ││
││       sliding         ││
││        panel          ││
└┴───────────────────────┴┘

The sliding panel detects up or down swipe that toggles the size of the panel. I have two problems that are probably related --

If the content in the sliding panel is more than the panel's height, one should be able to scroll down. For this, I have set the overflow-y of the panel to auto. However, while the scrollbar becomes visible as necessary on the responsive views available in the dev tools of the various browsers (tested in Firefox, Safari and Chrome), the scrolling action just does not work on my phone. I have asked a question about this separately.

However, I also just noticed that when I swipe up or down on the sliding panel, the swipe action goes through the panel and also affects the map underneath. Of course, I don't want this to happen. But, I am now thinking that my two problems are probably related.


A live example can be viewed on both a desktop browser as well as a phone.
In my code for catching the start and end of swipes, I have the appropriate event.preventDefault() as below
_startSwipe: function(evt) {
    const touch = evt.touches && evt.touches[0];

    if (!touch || !this._map) {
        return;
    }

    if (evt.target && evt.target.tagName == 'A') {
        return;
    }

    this._startPoint = this._map.mouseEventToContainerPoint(touch);
    L.DomEvent.preventDefault(evt);
},

_endSwipe: function(evt) {
    const touch = evt.changedTouches && evt.changedTouches[0];

    if (!touch || !this._startPoint || !this._map) {
        return;
    }

    const endPoint = this._map.mouseEventToContainerPoint(touch);
    const diff = endPoint.subtract(this._startPoint),
        absX = Math.abs(diff.x),
        absY = Math.abs(diff.y);
    this._startPoint = null;

    if (absX < this.options.threshold && absY < this.options.threshold) {

        // Not enough distance
        return;
    }

    if (absX / absY > 0.5 && absX / absY < 2) {

        // Unclear direction
        return;
    }

    let direction;
    let value;

    if (absX > absY) {
        value = absX;
        direction = diff.x < 0 ? 'left' : 'right';
    } 
    else {
        value = absY;
        direction = diff.y < 0 ? 'up' : 'down';
    }

    this.fire('swipe' + direction, {
        direction,
        value
    });
}

